# ESAPI validation is not accepting a particular regEx

Tags: regex, owasp, esapi

i want to validate an input string with alphanumeric chars, and square brackets and hypen for example `[Z01-Z02]` for this i set a validation property as

```
Validator.SqBrackText=^[0-9a-zA-Z \[\]\-]{1,111}$
```

But ESAPI.validator().getValidInput(context, input, "SqBrackText", maxLen, allowNull, true);

gives exception as in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The selected type [SqBrackText] was not set via the ESAPI validation configuration
        at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:215)
```

obviously ESAPI is not accepting the validation property although regExTester accepts the rule. 
There are other validation property rules in this same file which ESAPI is OK with.

Can anyone suggest what may be wrong or missing in this.

thanks

Comment: I dont think it solves your question, but let me suggest an improvement in you regex: ^\[[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+\]$

Comment: basicaly, if you know context, it is always a good idea to narrow down, to avoid matching undesired input.
yours: https://regex101.com/r/pFInEd/1/
 , my: https://regex101.com/r/dr5on4/1/

Comment: You are assigning the regex not as a String, could it be the Problem?

Comment: If you are  using a String, have you done escapings?  Because the regex has sins like slashes. They need to be escaped in Java.

Comment: I am not familiar how java parses the property. it could be a problem with the ^ $ or the {} in the property. Because basicaly java says there is no property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well got the solution - need to give 2 backslash to escape the `[]-` chars.

so used this regex and it worked OK

```
  Validator.SqBrackText=^[0-9a-zA-Z \\[\\]\\-]{1,1024}$
```

thx for all the help !